# Does law of large numbers converge in $L^1$?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, alternative-proof

I've seen the [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) stated mainly in two (or three) forms: $S_n/n$ converges in probability (weak law) and converges almost surely (strong law).  Also, there is convergence in the $L^2$-norm for uncorrelated random variables ($L^2$ weak law).

However there is a backwards martingale proof of the strong law of large numbers (any graduate level probability theory book, for example Durrett, should have it).  The important thing is that $M_{-n}:=S_n/n$ is a backward martingale, and backward martingales converge both a.e. and in the $L^1$-norm.  Then, in particular, $S_n/n$ converges in the $L^1$-norm.

> Does $S_n/n$ really converge in the $L^1$-norm?
>
> - If yes, why is this never mentioned?
> - If no, what is wrong with my above proof?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, $\bar X_n = S_n / n$ converges to $\mu$ in $\mathscr{L}_1$. It suffices to show that $\bar X_n$ is uniformly integrable since we already know $\bar X \to \mu$ in probability. This follows very quickly from the fact that the $X_i$ are trivially uniformly integrable (just fix $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta > 0$ so that if $P(A) < \delta$ then $\int_A |X_n| \ dP < \epsilon$ for all $n$ and show this $\delta$ also works for $\bar X_n$). You also need to show $\sup E|\bar X_n| < \infty$ but this follows from the triangle inequality since $X_1 \in \mathscr L_1$.

I don't know that I would say that this isn't mentioned. I know it is an exercise in Chung's book, and I would be surprised if it wasn't also in Billingsley somewhere. People don't seem to care that much about $\mathscr L_p$ convergence around these parts because a.s. convergence and convergence in $P$ seem to come up more in practical settings, but that's just the way it seems to me as a statistics student.

Comment: It's also an exercise in Resnick's *A Probability Path*.  And I assigned it as homework in a course last year :)

Comment: Thanks!  I probably didn't look hard enough. I was mostly looking in Durrett and on the Internet.  (Maybe it was even an exercise Durrett and I missed it.)

Comment: L1 boundedness is not sufficient for uniform integrability. This answer is false.

Comment: The correct way to do it is to use the lemma that $E|X|<\infty$ implies that there exists a convex function $\phi$ such that $\phi(x)/x \to \infty$. And then show that $\sup_n E\phi|\bar{X}_n| < \infty$

Comment: @DanielLi the $X_i$'s are uniformly integrable because they are iid; we are using more than $L_1$-boundedness.  You then use that to show the average $\bar X_n$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: @DanielLi see also this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569825/sample-mean-is-uniformly-integrable

Comment: @guy In the answer you did not mention condition (b) in the linked answer which is essential to the proof. That is, you just checked (a) and that $\{X_n\}$ are UI without stating it is necessary to check (b) also which is not exactly trivial. This is very misleading to those who are not familiar with the linked question. Therefore, I will not take down my comment and suggest you edit the answer.

Comment: @DanielLi I mentioned both conditions; I specifically stated that you need to check that $A,\epsilon,\delta$ condition and that you need to check that $\sup_n E|\bar X_n|<\infty$. I even stated how to check (b): fix $\epsilon$ and get the $\delta$ you get from the UI condition on the $X_i$’s and show it also works for $\bar X_n$, which is easy to check.

Comment: @guy Thank you - I just discovered the question and its answer. I understand that showing the uniform integrability is the key to show the $L^1$ convergence, but I'm also wondering if we can come up with a bound for $E|\bar{X_n}-\mu|$ as a decreasing function of $n$ that goes to zero as $n\to \infty.$ May be something like  $E|\bar{X_n}-\mu|\le C\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ or some sort of explicit such inequality from where the $L^1$ convergence will follow - do we have such an inequality? Thanks again!

Comment: @LearningMath Off the top of my head I don't know, but my intuition is that you cannot get a rate like $\sqrt N$. If $X \in L^2$ then the rate is easy by Jensen's inequality, but I guess you won't be able to get a rate like that if $X \in L^{1 + \epsilon}$ for only small $\epsilon$. I did some simple simulations with a density $f(x) \propto 1 / |x|^{2 + \epsilon} I(|x| > 1)$ and it seemed empirically that the rate can be arbitrarily bad.

Comment: @guy Thank you! So I asked this question here and the only answer I got so far was a consequence of Höffding's inequality. But since you wrote that the bound is attained using Jensen's inequality, perhaps you could answer the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863996/bound-on-expected-norm-of-the-difference-between-the-sample-mean-barx-n-and/4864051#4864051 ?