# Uniform integrability of the average of i.i.d.s

Tags: probability-theory

So I'm being asked to show that for an i.i.d ${X_i}$, ${n^{-1}S_n}$  is uniformly integrable provided $X_i\in L_1$  My professor keeps insisting that $S_n$ is a number and not a random variable, which it seems like it should be a random variable to me.

In any case, I'm trying to prove $n^{-1}S_n$ converges in $L_p$ to $X_1$,  thus it is $u.i.$,  and it seems trivial to me, but my professor kept saying no, in an accent I can't make out.   It seems to me that $E(n^{-1}S_n)=n^{-1}E(\sum _{k=1}^nX_k)=n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E(X_k)=n^{-1}nE(X_1)=E(X_1)$,  since they are i.id,  so of course they converge in expectation to $X_1$, which is the definition of $L_1$ convergence.  Is this wrong?

Comment: $S_n$ is certainly a random variable. It's not clear if you're interested in showing that $n^{-1}S_n$ is uniformly integrable for a fixed $n$ (which is obvious) or that the set $\{n^{-1}S_n\mid n\geq 1\}$ is uniformly integrable. If it is indeed the latter, then [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569825/sample-mean-is-uniformly-integrable) is a couple of hints. Side note: Convergence of the expectations is not the definition of $L^1$ convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^{-1}S_n$ converges in $L^1$ and a.s. to $\mathbb{E} (X_1)$, by the Strong law of large numbers. Then notice the fact that
\begin{equation}
X_n \in L^1 \, \,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, (X_n) \text{ converges to } X \text{ in } L^1 \Longleftrightarrow  (X_n) \text{ converges to } X \text{ in probability and } (X_n) \text{ is U.I. }
\end{equation}

Comment: That's the theorem I was trying to use,  just needed the reasoning for $n^{-1}S_n$ converging.  Thanks

Comment: @Alan: The $L^1$ convergence of the strong law of large numbers usually relies on the fact that $\{n^{-1}S_n\mid n\geq 1\}$ and hence in this case, this is a circular argument.

Comment: You need to use a backwards martingale argument (standard) to prove the Strong Law of Large Numbers.