# Bound on expected norm of the difference between the sample mean $\bar{X_n}$ and population mean $\mu$ as a function of the sample size $n$ for LLN?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers, rate-of-convergence

My question is motivated by this question:

[Does law of large numbers converge in $L^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78445/does-law-of-large-numbers-converge-in-l1)

that asks about the the convergence in $L^1$-norm of the sample mean $\bar{X_n}$ to the population mean $\mu.$

I looked at the answers and comments and I understood that the answer was in the affirmative, and the proof uses the fact that the sample means [$\bar{X_n}$ are **uniformly integrable(UI)**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569825/sample-mean-is-uniformly-integrable?noredirect=1&lq=1). The two steps a) and b) outlined in the previous link follow immediately using:

triangle inequality for norms, exchanging finite sum and integrals and then using that $X_i\sim_{iid}X,$ and finally $\mathbb{E}||X-\mu||< \infty.$

While the **use of UI** does ***indirectly*** show that the Law of Large Numbers (LLN) is true in $L^1,$ I still wonder if there's a bound like the below where $\{X_i\}\sim_{iid} X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d, \bar{X_n}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i, \mu:=\mathbb{E}[X]:$

$$\mathbb{E}||\bar{X_n}-\mu||\le C_X \frac{1}{\phi(n)}, \phi(n)\to \infty, n \to \infty?$$

Here $C_X$ is a constant depending only upon $X,$ and my guesses for possible choices for $\phi(n)$ would be $n$ or $\sqrt{n}$ etc. but not sure. But anyway, is there such an explicit bound? Resources, links or deductions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $X \in L^2$ then by Jensen's inequality and the fact that $\sqrt{x}$ is concave we have

$$
  E(|\bar X_n - \mu|) = E\left(\sqrt{(\bar X_n - \mu)^2}\right)
  \le \sqrt{\text{Var}(\bar X_n)} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$

The $\sqrt n$ rate is sharp, as it is obtained when the $X_i$'s are iid from a normal distribution. As mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78445/does-law-of-large-numbers-converge-in-l1/78454?noredirect=1#comment10374105_78454), my belief is that the rate can be arbitrarily poor for $X \in L^1$, and in particular the density $f(x) \propto 1 / |x|^{2 + \epsilon} I(|x| > 1)$ seems to have a rate $n^{\psi(\epsilon)}$ for some $\psi(\epsilon) \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ (I did not attempt to determine what $\psi(\epsilon)$ is).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of such bound in the case of $P(X_1\in [a,b])=1$. Set $M=b-a$ and $S_n=X_1+...++X_n$ and by [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) we get
$$\begin{aligned}E[|\overline{X}_n-\mu|]&=\frac{1}{n}E[|{S}_n-n\mu|]\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty P(|{S}_n-n\mu|>t)dt\\
&\leq \frac{2}{n}\int_0^\infty \exp\bigg(-\frac{2t^2}{nM^2}\bigg)dt\\
&=M\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}
\end{aligned}$$