# $\{X_n,n>1\}$i.i.d,$S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$,$E(X_1) = 0$.Prove that $E|S_n|/n→0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $\{X_n,n>1\}$i.i.d,$S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$,$E(X_1) = 0$.Prove that $E|S_n|/n→0$.

Attempts:$\{X_n^+\}$ i.i.d and $\{X_n^-\}$ i.i.d,we have $E(|S_n|)$=$E|\sum_i X_i^+-\sum_j X_j^-|$ and $E(\sum_i X_i^+)=E(\sum_j X_j^-)$,and from Strong Law of Large Numbers,we have $\sum_n X_n^+/n\to E(X_1^+)$ a.e and $\sum_n X_n^-/n\to E(X_1^-)$ a.e,but there are still gaps between the final result.

Comment: This is just the strong law of large numbers; notice that  $|S_n|/n=|S_n/n|$

Comment: Pls use the fact that $\{X_n, S_n/n, n\ge 1\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a reply to @Snoop's comment. The claim can be regarded as the $L^1$ version of LLN. The following proof does not use LLN. We assume $X_1 \in L^1$.

We use a truncation argument. For $M > 0$ and $i \ge 1$, we let $X_i^{(M)} := ((-M) \vee X_i) \wedge M$.

Step 1. For fixed $M > 0$, consider $X_i^{(M)}, i \ge 1$. They are i.i.d., so we have that $$E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i^{(M)} - E[X_i^{(M)}]) \right)^2\right] = n \text{Var}(X_1^{(M)}) \le n M^2.$$

Hence
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} E\left[ \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^{(M)} - E\left[X_1^{(M)}\right]\right)^2\right] = 0.$$
Hence,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} E\left[ \, \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^{(M)} - E\left[X_1^{(M)}\right]\right| \, \right] = 0.$$

Step 2. We deal with $X_i - X_i^{(M)}, i \ge 1$. By the triangle inequality,
$$E\left[ \, \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - X_i^{(M)})\right| \, \right] \le E\left[\left|X_1 - X_1^{(M)}\right|\right].$$

Therefore, for each $M > 0$,
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} E\left[ \left| \frac{S_n}{n} - E\left[X_1^{(M)}\right] \right| \right] \le E\left[\left|X_1 - X_1^{(M)}\right|\right].$$

Furthermore, by recalling that $E[X_1] = 0$,
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} E\left[ \left| \frac{S_n}{n} \right| \right] \le 2E\left[\left|X_1 - X_1^{(M)}\right|\right].$$

We have that $\left|X_1 - X_1^{(M)}\right| \le |X_1|$, $X_1^{(M)} \to X_1$, $M \to \infty$, and recall that $X_1 \in L^1$. Now we can apply the Lebesgue convergence theorem and obtain that
$$ E\left[\left|X_1 - X_1^{(M)}\right|\right] \to 0, M \to \infty. $$

Thus we obtain the assertion.

Comment: I don't follow how $E[X_1]=0$ implies $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} E\left[ \left| \frac{S_n}{n} \right| \right] \le 2E\left[\left|X_1 - X_1^{(M)}\right|\right]. $$ ?

Comment: By the triangle inequality, we see that $$\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right| = \left|\frac{S_n}{n}-E[X_1]\right| \le  \left|\frac{S_n}{n}-E[X_1^{(M)}]\right| + |E[X_1^{(M)}] - E[X_1]|$$ and then take the expectation and the limit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following fact to prove it:

### Proposition

> Let $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $\{Y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
> be sequences of $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables
> such that $\lvert X_n \rvert \leq Y_n$ a.s. for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
> Let $X$, $Y$ be $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables
> such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n = Y$ a.s..
> Suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \mathbb{E}[Y] < \infty$.
> Then,
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_n] 
> = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n]
> = \mathbb{E}[X].
> $$

This is a version of Proposition A.58. in [Theory of Statistics, by Mark J. Schervish](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4250-5) rewritten in the terms of probability theory.
And the proof of this proposition can be done in the same way as the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

### Proof of your question

Let $Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lvert X_n \rvert / n$.
By the trigonometric inequality,
we have $\lvert S_n \rvert / n \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lvert X_n \rvert / n = Y_n$.
And by the Strong Law of Large Numbers and the continuity of the absolute function, we have

$$
\frac{\lvert S_n \rvert}{n} = \left\lvert \frac{S_n}{n} \right\rvert
 \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} \lvert \mathbb{E}[X_1] \rvert = 0,
~Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lvert X_n \rvert
 \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} \mathbb{E}[\lvert X_1 \rvert].
$$

Furthermore, by the linearity of the expectation,
it follows that $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \mathbb{E}[\lvert X_1 \rvert] \to \mathbb{E}[\lvert X_1 \rvert] < \infty ~(n \to \infty)$.

Therefore, by the Proposition, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\lvert S_n \rvert}{n} \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lvert S_n \rvert}{n} \right]
= 0.
$$

Comment: OP's claim [*is part of* the LLN](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78445/does-law-of-large-numbers-converge-in-l1), so a different proof may be more interesting if the LLN is not used at all